# APPCRASH - myapp.exe started crashing from VB6

Tags: vb6, crash, dep

I've an exe (app1) which is written in VB6, this is called from another VB6 application (app2). This was working all these years and recently started crashing. When I'm riunning app2 and where app1 called is crashing with the following error.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: myapp1.exe
  Application Version:  6.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    470bfe05
  Fault Module Name:    ole32.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17514
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ce7b96f
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00066b21
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.28
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: a7aa
  Additional Information 2: a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d
  Additional Information 3: a7aa
  Additional Information 4: a7aa91f17ea749d42a4de3b390fa5b3d
```

This is crashing only in some machines, it's working in machines with same configuration.
I've tried disabling DEP for this exe, that doesn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These shouldn't occur in a VB6 program unless it uses API calls in a cavalier manner.  Such a program can run just fine until something in the data it works with causes it to fall over on one of these access violation errors.

See [What is a C0000005 crash?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2004/06/30/170344.aspx)

Comment: I don't have any API calls in the exe,   Fault Module Name:    ole32.dll, is it something related to any MS updates?